# Is it normal to see ClassNotFoundException when opening Google Plus app?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung

I recently have my first Android phone.  It is a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime (KitKat).  It is not rooted yet and all apps are from Google Play.

Every time I launched Google Plus or Google Photo, I see the following `Exception` in logcat:

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: itw
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: itw
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native method)
   ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "itw" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

`com.google.android.talk` also have the following single error message without stack trace (these errors are from the same process id):

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'av', referenced from method f.a
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'ax', referenced from method f.a
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method f.a
E/Babel: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc
E/Babel: canonicalizeMccMnc: inavlid mcccmnc nullnull
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.libraries.hangouts.video.ScreenCaptureVideoSource$2', referenced from method com.google.android.libraries.hangouts.video.ScreenCaptureVideoSource.<init>`
```

Looks like `itw`, `ax`, `f.a`, etc are obfuscated names.  I would like to know wether these errors are normal or not.

*Added more information to question*:

Google+ is a built-in application located in `/system/app/PlusOne.apk`.  As I don't have root access, I can't remove and reinstall it.  Based on process id, looks like `/system/bin/tlc_server` raised this exception.  I don't have any idea what is `tlc_server`.  If I use the original version without updates, exception is raised when I view any photo (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hay`) or opening G+ (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ejf`).  After upgrading to the latest version of Google+, the following exception appears only for the first run:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: eqb; Incompatible class (SUID): eqb: static final long serialVersionUID =8874316054258000122L; but expected eqb: static final long serialVersionUID =0L;
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndinit(ObjectInputStream.java:2343)
   ...
   at com.google.android.apps.plus.service.EsServie.d(PG:5584)
   ...
   at elj.a(PG:70)
   at bd.b(PG:425)
   at bd.a(PG:395)
   at dm.b(PG:104)
   at dh.a(PG:73)
   at iak.a(PG:120)
   at iak.b(PG:16)
   at dg.a(PG:61)
   at dt.b(PG:47)
   at dz.handleMessage(PG:474)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are not normal, I don't have them.

For the google talk error, do you have hangouts installed?

And for the g+ error, have you tried reinstalling the app, or a full factory reset.

Comment: Yes, both G+ and Hangout are default apps that comes with this device (`/system/app/PlusOne.apk` and `/system/app/Hangouts.apk`).  This device even has `line-4.3.0-release-20140428133612-MA_SAM.apk` as prebuilt apps.  I can't remove them but I've tried to delete upgrades and caches for G+.  Exceptions still occur when viewing photo.  They seems to be raised by `/system/bin/tlc_server`.

Comment: Have you disabled any apps?